# How to avoid POST request response Unknown event codes

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-post

I'm running a nodejs server and my client makes POST requests to the server. However on POST response I get these "unknown event 72" etc as in below screenshot of wireshark. These unnecessary data increase application bandwidth usage. 
This is how I handle the response. Appreciate any tips to avoid these  sending back with POST response.

```js
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
res.end();
```

[Screenshot of wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5OLI.png)

Comment: `I get these as in below screenshot of wireshark` - which ones are "these"

Comment: @JaromandaXj edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
```